# $L^1$ functions at $\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am having trouble with a practice prelim question:

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_n^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$

I know that $f$ is bounded, but I am not if I should add and subtract by something convenient or if I should try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $f$ is not necessarily bounded. $f(x)=\frac{\chi_{(0,1]}(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ is an unbounded (Lebesgue) integrable function (its integral is $2$).

Hint: try to argue that $\int_{-\infty}^n f(x) dx$ converges to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ by using the dominated convergence theorem. Then notice that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^n f(x) dx = \int_n^\infty f(x) dx.$

An additional hint: a nice trick in problems involving the application of some integral convergence theorem is to make the domain of all the integrals be the entire space, by multiplying by the characteristic function of the set over which you want to integrate. So for instance $\int_n^\infty f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \chi_{[n,\infty)}(x) dx$.

Comment: In fact, that is the definition of integration over a subset of the measure space.

Comment: @zhw. I wouldn't say it is *the* definition; another perfectly good definition would define $\int_A f(x) dx$ by making $A$ a measure space in its own right (where the $\sigma$-algebra consists of the measurable sets which are subsets of $A$, and the measure is the restriction of the original measure). But it is certainly *a* definition, and it is probably the most convenient definition.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that is the definition in Rudin.

Comment: So if I apply Holder's Inequality to the above, then I should get something like

$\big|\int_{n}^{\infty} f \big| = \big| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \chi_{[n,\infty)} \big| \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \big| f \chi_{[n,\infty)} \big| \le \|f\|_1 \|\chi_{[n,\infty)} \|_{\infty}$

Then since $f \in L^1$, it is bounded by say some $M > 0$.  Then the limit of $\chi_{[n,\infty)}$ goes to 0?  Would this be a correct solution?

Comment: @user0430 You need a *pointwise* bound: $|f(x) \chi_{[n,\infty)}(x)| \leq |f(x)|$. Then since $f \in L^1$ and $f \chi_{[n,\infty)} \to 0$ pointwise, you get your result by the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Well the part $\int_{-\infty}^nf(x)dx$ must converge to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ so the part $\int_n^{-\infty}f(x)dx$ must go to zero.  Just write the whole integral as a sum of those two parts and take the limit.